# Write sqlite3 table into text file in python3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I want to import a sqlite3 file into a text file in python.I made my sqlite3 file in python and i want to write my table into a text file.How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

For write a table in db sqlite3 file into a text file i made this cod and it worked:

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('a.sqlite')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE users(col1,col2,col3 )''')
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO 
users(col1,col2,col3)VALUES(?,?,?)'''('a','b','c'))
myfile = open('myfile','w')
myfile.write('col1'.rjust(0))
myfile.write('col2'.rjust(5))
myfile.write('col3'.rjust(5))
myfile.writelines('') #create a line between rows
x = cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM users ''' )
for row in x:
  row = str(row)
  myfile.write("\n%s\n" % row)
db.commit()
myfile.close()
```

the output of text file is this:

```
col1 col2 col3

('a', 'b', 'c')

('a', 'b', 'c')

('a', 'b', 'c')

('a', 'b', 'c')
```

If is there another way to write a db file into text file, please guide me